# How to Publish an Office(Word) add-in created using Script Lab

Tags: javascript, office-addins, word-addins, appsource, scriptlab

I have created a Word add-in using Script Lab , the code is Written in JavaScript , Html also  jQuery .the development of the add-in is already done , i just want to publish it on Store ,and any one can access it .